# Hessian of the following function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I'm trying to build a gradient descent model using newtons method and require the Hessian of:

$$f(w) = \frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n\log(1 + \exp(-y_iw^Tx_i))$$

I believe I've found the $j^\text{th}$ partial to be:

$$\frac{\partial f(w)}{\partial w_j} = w_j + C \sum_{i=1}^n -x_{ij}y_i \frac{\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)}{1 + \exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)}$$

And so the gradient would just be the vector of all these from $w_1,\ldots, w_d$. To derive the hessian I figured I would have to find $\frac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_j^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_j \, \partial w_k}$, so far I have:

Let
$$M_i = \exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_j^2} = 1 + C\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}^2y_i^2 \frac{M_i}{(1+M_i)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_j \, \partial w_k} = C\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} x_{ik} y_i^2 \frac{M_i}{(1+M_i)^2}$$

This looks right-ish, but I cant figure out how to pull a matrix out of here. It looks something like $(X^TX  + I)y^2M$ where $M$ is some combo of my $M_i$s but I dont think thats correct.

Comment: I changed things like this: $f(w) = \frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n\log(1 + \exp(-y_iw^Tx_i))$ to things like this: $$ f(w) = \frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + \exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)) $$ and $exp$ and $log$ to $\exp$ and $\log$ (the backslash not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $3\log5$ and $3\log(5),$ where I include both examples to show the context-dependent nature of the spacing). And I changed $||w||$ to $\|w\|.$ But one thing every mathematician should know is that the proper notation for a$\, \ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$mixed partial derivative is not $\dfrac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_i w_j},$ but $\dfrac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_i\, \partial w_j}.$ (Note that I wrote $\dfrac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_i\, \partial w_j}$ and NOT $\dfrac{\partial^2 f(w)}{\partial w_i \partial w_j}.$ That difference appears not to be conspicuous to many people, if one judges by their typesetting behavior.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy TY! I will admit im a comp sci guy not a math guy, but as I'm getting into the twilight of my degree things are starting to blend